# Read HttpWebResponse with Content-Type : multipart/x-mixed-replace in c#

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have an Asp.Net application that I need to display a video feed. The video feed has a **Httpwebresponse** with content type  '**multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary**'.

```cs
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamToRead,Encoding.ASCII)
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I have tried using string reader but it didnt work. 
Kindly let me know how to read(access) the response with content-type **multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary** .

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean your ASP.Net application is a server responding with such multipart response to a .NET Core client like UWP or WPF, because the server is like a console app that cannot *display* videos. Otherwise, the server may forward the stream chunk by chunk to the client as-is. You cannot `.ReadToEnd()` for live video feed that has not ended.

```cs
// using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers; // to parse the boundary from the content type
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities; // to read each part of multipart

using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(response.ContentType);
    var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary).Value;
    for (var streamReader = new MultipartReader(boundary, responseStream); ;)
    {
        var nextFrame = await streamReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (nextFrame == null)
            break;
        DisplayOneFrameCallback(nextFrame.Body);
    }
}
```

You then need to implement `DisplayOneFrameCallback()` which take a stream of one frame at a time and feed a bitmap decoder like below:

```cs
// for UWP, copy the stream to an InMemoryRandomAccessStream via a Dispatcher
myBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(memoryStreamOfOneFrame);
```

Please provide more details of your question if this does not answer it.